# How to define a route and map it to an action in the module.config.php of a Zend Framework 2 application module?

Tags: routes, action, zend-framework2

My application has a module `Catalog` that should display three views:

- List of cities, when the URI is `/catalog/`
- List of sports in the `%city%`, when the URI is `/catalog/%city%`
- List of courses of the `%sport%` in the `%city%`, when the URI is `/catalog/%city%/%sport%`

My routing options are currently looking like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'catalog' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/catalog[/:city][/:sport][/]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'city'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'sport' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

My `CatalogController`:

```
class CatalogController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function listCitiesAction() {} // all cities

    public function listSportsAction() {} // all sports for the city

    public function listCoursesAction() {} // all courses for the sport in the city
}
```

How can I define the route so, that it's mapped to the actions above?

Thx

Comment: OK, I think, I've found the answer: I need a route for the `listCitiesAction()`, a `child_route` of it for the `listSportsAction()` and a futher `child_route` (of the `listSportsAction()` child route) for the `listCoursesAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'catalog' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/catalog',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'city' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/:city',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'city'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'sport' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                            'action'     => 'list-sports',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'sport' => array(
                            'type'    => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/:sport',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'city'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'sport' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                                    'action'     => 'list-courses',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I think you meant to say: "You can use child routes to individually map the routes to different actions"

Comment: When I asked this question, I didn't know anything about the `child_route` option.

Comment: Oops! My bad I did not realize that you were the one that asked the question :P